# Copying OpenJDK folder present at /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.38.x86_64 from one system to another

Tags: java, linux, installation

I installed OpenJDK 6 on CentOS 6.7 VM using "yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel". This created a folder /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.38.x86_64/. Can i zip this folder, copy it to another machine and use java present in this folder on that machine? Are there any symbolic links that are created when i do yum install which will be missed when i zip the folder?

**Purpose**: I am writing a program which will download specified JDK version and start another java process with this JDK. All my machines where this program will be used have the same OS (CentOS 6.7).

Answer (score 0):

Why not [working with Yum Cache](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Working_with_Yum_Cache.html)?

The following command returns the path to rpms:

```
find /var/cache/yum -iname '*.rpm' –
```

The rpm cache directory location can be found in `/etc/yum.conf`

```
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
```

You should change the `$basearch` and `$releasever`, values based on your red hat release version.

If you want to keep the rpm cache after installation the keep cache value should be set 1 in:

```
/etc/yum.conf
```

set

```
keepcache=1
```